# How can i connect to mongodb database with native nodejs without using the official MongoDB Node.js Driver?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

I searched many answers through google, but all suggestions are to install mongodb through npm. Then i tried to analyze MongoDB Node.js Driver source code, where are  [mongodb library](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native). And found that it seems to be implemented through nodejs's native net module. Can someone give me some pointers, thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Why would you even want to do that?

Comment: Just to understand the underlying mechanism more clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can connect to mongod/mongos's ports using your favorite socket library and speak the raw protocol directly. The handshake is described [here](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/mongodb-handshake/handshake.rst). OP_MSG which is used with 3.6 and newer servers is described [here](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/message/OP_MSG.rst). See also [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-wire-protocol/). You may need to read some driver source to figure out how to attach everything together (for example, the messages need to be serialized to bson for transmission over the wire).

Comment: Appreciate your help. I will adopt your answer and mark your answer as useful until I figure it out completely.